# Teradata - Convert 'yyyy-mm-dd' into YYYY-MM

Tags: datetime, casting, teradata, converters

I have an issue changing `DATE` format column (`CREATE_DT`) ('yyyy-mm-dd') but I want to create a new column `CREATE_Month` that has ('yyyy-mm') only

I have tried

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DT,'%Y%m') 
from SCHEMA.Tables
```

Also

```sql
select * 
from (
  Select top 100 *
  from SCHEMA.Tables
  where cast(CREATE_DT AS DATE)  
) AS CREATE_Month
```

Below is my CREATE table code if that helps,

```sql
CREATE MULTISET TABLE SCHEMA.Tables ,NO FALLBACK ,
  NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
  NO AFTER JOURNAL,
  CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
  DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
  (     
    ACCT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CREATE_DT DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'
PRIMARY INDEX ( ACCT_ID );
```

I expect the solution to have 3 columns

```sql
ACCT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CREATE_DT DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
CREATE_Month (derived from CREATE_DT)
```

If anyone can help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: `select to_char(CREATE_DT, 'YYYY-MM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to add a new "month" field to your table or do you just want to format the `CREATE_DT` field in a `SELECT` query?  There is no "month" data type, so if you want to add a `CREATE_Month` field, you could do a couple things:

1. Create a new `DATE` field and just default the `day` part to the first of the month
2. Create a new `VARCHAR(10)` and store it as a string

If you plan to do partitioning (PPI) based on this field or any date manipulation / calculations, option #1 is better.  If you're just using it for display, then either one works.

If all you want to do is return `CREATE_DT` in a different format, you can use this:

```sql
SELECT CREATE_DT (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Ok got it! So you cannot just get month from DATE I have to change to varchar then get the month. Thanks for that I worked it out now

Comment: You're welcome.  You can extract the month value from a `DATE` column easily using something like this: `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MyDateColumn)`.  But that will just give you the `MONTH` value (i.e. 2 for February) and not the `yyyy-mm` format you specified in your original question.